# How do I check after uploading files to the host

Tags: php, host, digital-ocean

A very rookie question but I was not able to find any good answers.

I uploaded 3 php files to my host using FileZilla. One of my php files (name is dbtest.php) is connecting to a database and it should display "Success" if the connection is successful ("error" if not)

My host is 188.166.***.***

My question is how do I view the php file output in the browser?

When I was uploading to my localhost, I can access the file as such: 127.0.0.1/{foldername}/dbtest.php but when I try 188.166.***.***/{foldername}/dbtest.php I get an error saying "The requested URL /vod_api/dbtest.php was not found on this server."

But I can access the file using:
ftp://188.166.***.***/{foldername}/dbtest.php

Although it doesn't show the output ("success"/"error") It just shows the php code

UPDATE
The url is 188.166.{number1}.{number2}. The asterix I used have got cut off

Comment: what folder did you place it in?

Comment: I placed it in the master folder. The folder with the name "/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, you need to put it in `public_html` folder. not all the folders are accessible on web, some of these folders hold server settings and some are for your php application use only.

Edit: the `public_html` folder can have different names depending upon server. like `www`. best if you check with your hosting provider for details if you can't find the `www` or `public_html` folder.

For more help you can see **[here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/what-is-the-correct-folder-to-put-my-website-files-var-www-or-var-www-html)**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. There was a html folder with index.html. I put my folder into that folder and it works now.